# Calling StartActivity(intent) method from another class

Tags: android-intent

I have a method that I want to call from a number of places in my application.

```
public void openURL(String urlToOpen) {
    if (!urlToOpen.startsWith("https://") && !urlToOpen.startsWith("http://")){
        urlToOpen = "http://" + urlToOpen;
    }

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlToOpen));

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

I can call the method from within the class where the method is created, but I want to call the same method from elsewhere in my application.

At the minute I'm getting a `NullPointerException`

```
04-23 13:08:08.958  22761-22761/com.myapplication. E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapplication, PID: 22761
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:323)
        at com.myapplication.MyMethodHandler.openURL(MyMethodHandler.java:213)
        at com.myapplication.HistoryListActivity$1.onClick(HistoryListActivity.java:111)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer that I should've spotted earlier.

I just added a `Context` parameter to the method and used this when calling the `startActivity` method:

```
public void openURL(Context context, String urlToOpen) {
    if (!urlToOpen.startsWith("https://") && !urlToOpen.startsWith("http://")){
        urlToOpen = "http://" + urlToOpen;
    }

final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlToOpen));

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

}

Then got the Context from the class that was attempting to call the method:

`Context context = this.getApplicationContext();`

and passed this when calling the method:

`handler.openURL(context, urlToOpen);`